# Samsung np-R440l edgescrolling not working

Tags: 11.10

well in short i need help when i first got my laptop and installed ubuntu 10.04 32bit version the touchpad edgescrolling worked fine, but ever-since upgrading to 10.10 64 bit(right now currently running 11.10 64bit) edge scrolling still is not working, please help me out here would appreciate it very much.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Is it an elantech or synaptics touchpad? try opening a terminal and

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

If it works make it permanent by

- options `psmouse proto=imps | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/options.conf`

(this is an old workaround, I'm not 100% it will work in 11.10 64bit)

another option is to take a look at this [package of tools specifically for samsung @sourceforge](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa).

[Homepage & forum for samsung-tools](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=15)